# Expo can't connect to android-studio emulator (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, expo, android-sdk-tools

When I run "npm start" and then 'a'/ "sudo expo start --android" the connection to the android emulator fails.
the error I get is:

```
Couldn't start project on Android: Error running adb: No Android connected device found, and no emulators could be started automatically.
Please connect a device or create an emulator (https://docs.expo.io/workflow/android-studio-emulator).
Then follow the instructions here to enable USB debugging:
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#developer-device-options. If you are using Genymotion go to Settings -> ADB, select "Use custom Android SDK tools", and point it at your Android SDK directory.
```

While trying to debug it I found:

- The app is running on web browser
- While launching the AVD on emulator on android-studio I get on android studio events:

  ```
   Emulator: E0810 10:41:04.480101550 89662 socket_utils_common_posix.cc:201] check for SO_REUSEPORT: {"created":"@1597045264.480085451","description":"SO_REUSEPORT unavailable on compiling system","file":"/mnt/tmpfs/src/android/emu-master-dev/external/grpc/src/core/lib/iomgr/socket_utils_common_posix.cc","file_line":169}
  ```
- I Made sure that .bashrc includes the right SDK path: "export ANDROID_SDK=/home/user/Android/Sdk", and followed this [link](https://docs.expo.io/workflow/android-studio-emulator/)
- I'll mention that the emulator already ran my app, I'm not sure what changed the configuration and made the app not running on android-studio emulator. I re-install android-studio but it's still have no connction